# $ \operatorname{dist}(w,A) \ge \operatorname{dist}(w, \partial A)?$ What is the mistake in this proof?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-explanation, fake-proofs

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space, $w \in X$ amd $A \subseteq X$.

> $\partial A$ refers to the set of boundary points of the set $A$ defined as $\{ x \in X~|~ \operatorname{dist}(x,A)= 0 =  \operatorname{dist}(x,A^c) \}$.
>
> **The distance function** is defined as: $ \operatorname{dist}(w,A) = \inf \{d(w,a)\mid a \in A \}$
>
> **Property A :** Suppose $X$ is a set with the a totally ordering $<$. Suppose $z \in X$ and $A \subseteq  X $.Then, if $\inf A$ exists, then $z \le \inf A \iff z \le a ~\forall~ a \in A $

**The solution for proving that $ \operatorname{dist}(w,A) \le  \operatorname{dist}(w, \partial A)$  is as follows:**

If $\partial A = \phi,$ then $\operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) = \infty$ and the result holds. Otherwise, let us consider $z \in \partial A$. $\\$ And, by definition: $ \operatorname{dist}(z,A)=0\\ \operatorname{dist}(w,A) \le d(w,a) ~\forall a \in A \\d(w,a) \le d(w,z)+d(z,a)$

Using **Property A**: $d(w,a) \le   \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) +dist(z,a) = \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) $ which yields the required result.

> **Point of Confusion:** Can't we prove the other way inequality in a similar manner as well?
>
> \begin{align} \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) &\le d(w,z)\quad\forall z \in \partial A \\ &\le d(w,a)+d(a,z)\quad\forall a \in A
> \end{align}
>   Since the above inequality is valid for all $z $ and for all $a$, thus, using **Property A**:
>
> $ \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) \le  \operatorname{dist}(w,A) +  \operatorname{dist}(z,A)$ where $ \operatorname{dist}(z,A) = 0$.

Hence, the required result. I know the latter inequality is incorrect ( A counter example being a solid sphere with $w$ being the center of the sphere in the set of real numbers. )

**But what went wrong with the proof? And what's the difference between the proofs for the $1st$ and $2nd$ inequality?**

Any inputs will be really appreciated. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Certainly is false if $w$ is the center of $A$, where $A$ is a solid ball

Comment: @KennyLau could you please pinpoint where I did wrong? Thanks

Comment: I mean the statement is false.

Comment: @KennyLau yes I got it. I have tried to prove the other way inequality at the bottom of the question. Could you look at it and tell me where i went wrong?

Comment: It's even false when $x\notin \overline{A}$

Comment: Now one error in the first proof has been corrected, but the fundamental error that $$\operatorname{dist}(w,A) \leqslant d(w,z) + d(z,a) \geqslant \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) + \operatorname{dist}(z,A)$$ doesn't help in any way to obtain the desired conclusion remains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "proof" for the first inequality is already incorrect.

> Using **Property A**: $d(w,z) \le   \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A)$ **and** $d(z,a) \le  \operatorname{dist}(z,A) = 0$ which yields the required result.

is wrong. We have $\operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) \leqslant d(w,z)$ and $\operatorname{dist}(z,A) \leqslant d(z,a)$, but generically these inequalities are strict.

A correct way to finish the proof of $\operatorname{dist}(w,A) \leqslant \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A)$ from the - valid for all $a\in A$ and $z \in \partial A$ - inequality
$$\operatorname{dist}(w,A) \leqslant d(w,a) \leqslant d(w,z) + d(z,a)$$
is to pick a sequence $(a_n)$ in $A$ with $d(z,a_n) \to 0$. (Such a sequence exists for all $z \in \partial A$.). Then we obtain the inequality
$$\operatorname{dist}(w,A) \leqslant \lim_{n \to \infty} d(w,z) + d(z,a_n) = d(w,z)\,,$$
valid for all $z \in \partial A$. Taking the infimum over $z \in \partial A$ then yields $\operatorname{dist}(w,A) \leqslant \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A)$.

In the same way, in the attempt at the second inequality, we have
$$d(w,a) + d(a,z) \geqslant \operatorname{dist}(w,A) + \operatorname{dist}(z,A)\,,$$
and that points in the wrong way, from $X \leqslant S$ and $S \geqslant Y$ we cannot conclude any ordering relation between $X$ and $Y$.

Additionally, the attempt ignores the problem of $\partial A = \varnothing$, it assumes that there is a $z \in \partial A$ to use. And then there's the mistake that Kenny Lau already pointed out, there is no reason to suppose
$$\inf_{a \in A} \bigl(d(w,a) + d(a,z)\bigr) = \inf_{a\in A} d(w,a) + \inf_{a\in A} d(a,z)\,.$$
In general the left hand side is strictly larger than the right.

Comment: I have a question please.$ \begin{align} \operatorname{dist}(w,\partial A) &\le d(w,z)\quad\forall z \in \partial A \\ &\le d(w,a)+d(a,z)\quad\forall a \in A
\end{align}$ which means $d(w,z) \le \inf (d(w,a) + d(a,z) )$ and $\inf  (d(w,a) + d(a,z) )  = \inf d(w,a) + \inf d(a,z) = dist(w,A) + dist(a, \delta A)$

Comment: Would this conclusion be correct?

Comment: No, at the end there is the mistake pointed out by Kenny Lau. You can't distribute the $\inf$. Except in some special cases, you have $$\inf \bigl(d(w,a) + d(a,z)\bigr) > \inf d(w,a) + \inf d(a,z)\,.$$

Comment: Thank you very much.   Could you please also tell me under which special cases does the inf distribute?

Comment: I would just need a problem statement so that I could prove it for myself. thanks again!

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think there's a useful characterisation of when that happens. We have equality if and only if for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there is an $a_{\varepsilon}$ such that simultaneously $d(w,a_{\varepsilon}) < \varepsilon + \inf d(w,a)$ and $d(a_{\varepsilon},z) < \varepsilon + \inf d(a,z)$. But that's pretty much just a rephrasing of "the infimum distributes".

Comment: If there were not already answers, I would have described the logical error of "distributing the $\inf$" by saying that  it may not be possible to find $a\in A$ with  $d(w,a)$  arbitrarily close to dist$(a,A)$  and simultaneously have some $z\in \partial A$ such that  $d(a,z)$ is arbitrarily close to dist$ (z,A).$

Comment: @DanielFischer Sir, would you mind if I request your inputs for a very similar query here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223015/prove-that-da-b-le-inf-da-ss-in-s-inf-db-ss-in

Answer (score 0):

The mistake of the step from:
$$d(w,\partial A) \le d(w,a) + d(z,a) ~~~~ \forall a \in A$$
To:
$$d(w,\partial A) \le d(w,A) + d(z,A)$$
is that you wrongly assumed $\displaystyle \inf_{i \in I} (f(i) + g(i)) = \inf_{i \in I} f(i) + \inf_{i \in I} g(i)$.

What is true (but irrelevant here) is $\inf (A+B) = \inf A + \inf B$.

Comment: Could you please explain where exactly I assumed the above what you have stated? Also, the two sentences you typed seem same to me. Are you sure that isn't a typo?

Comment: Also, hasn't the author used the same to prove the first inequality as well?

Comment: I think Kenny Lau is correct.


The author had the following inequality: $\text{dist}(\omega,A) \leq d(\omega ,z)$ for every $z \in \partial A$, and he just takes the infimum of the two sides.

Comment: @Andrea S. What is the difference between proving the first and second in equality as shown above?

Comment: I can't understand the point where you have wrote:Using $\textbf{Property A}$…yields the required result.Actually the inequalities are true in the other way around, therefore if $z \in \partial A$ then$d(\omega,z)\geq d(\omega, \partial A)$ and if $a \in A$ then $d(z,a) \geq d(z,A)$. By definition of distance of a point from a set.

Comment: @AndreaS. i have used the property that if a quantity $k \le d(x,y) ~~|~~x \in Z~,\forall~y \in Y; Y \subseteq Z, $ then : $k \le d(x,Y)$

Comment: @Kenny Lau Hasn't the same mistake which you have talked about in your answer committed by the author in writing proof for the first inequality as well?

Comment: @MathMan when Kenny wrote $\inf(A+B) = \inf A + \inf B$, he is referring to a different kind of sum. Namely, if $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, we define $A+B$ as $\{a+b : a \in A, b \in B\}$.

Comment: @mathworker21 Thanks for the valuable point!

Comment: @mathworker21 I request your inputs for a very similar query here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3223015/prove-that-da-b-le-inf-da-ss-in-s-inf-db-ss-in

Answer (score 0):

You have used the property A incorrectly. You have $a\leq b+c$ with $b\geq B$ and $c\geq C$. You conclude from this that therefore $a\leq B+C$, which is simply a step that does not follow from the premise.

Comment: Could you please elaborate further where exactly i went wrong?

Comment: #MathMan Line 7 of your 'proof'. If you were submitting thus for assessment, you would have to justify the inequality on this line. You have not done this and it is really something you have to do. There is simply nothing available (from your premises) that we can use to deduce the mentioned inequality.

Comment: $d (w,a)\geq dist (w,A) $, for $a\in A $. Are you congusing 'dist' eith 'd'?

Comment: Nope. $dist(w,A) \le d(w,a)~\forall~a$

Comment: Sure. And then you have a problem doing the step in line 7.