# Prove that $d(a,b) \le \inf ~\{ ~d(a,s)~|~s \in S \} + \inf ~\{ ~d(b,s)~|~s \in S \} + \sup ~\{~d(b,s)~|~s \in S\}$. Error in proof?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, metric-spaces

Suppose $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $a,b \in X, S \subseteq X, S \ne \{\phi\}$.

Then, prove that $d(a,b) \le \inf ~\{ ~d(a,s)~|~s \in S \} + \inf ~\{ ~d(b,s)~|~s \in S \} + \sup ~\{~d(s_1,s_2)~|~s_1,s_2 \in S\}$

**My Textbook ( Metric Spaces by Michael Searcoid) gives the following proof :**

By definition of metric spaces :

$d(a,b) \le  d(a,s_1)  +  d(s_1,s_2) + d(b,s_2)$ where $s_1,s_2 \in S$

$~~~~~~~~~~~\le d(a,s_1)  + d(b,s_2) + \sup ~\{~d(s_1,s_2)~|~s_1,s_2 \in S\}~\forall s_1,.s_2 \in S$

$~~~~~~~~~~~$ where $\sup ~\{~d(s_1,s_2)~|~s_1,s_2 \in S\} = k$ is a constant.

$~~~~~~~~~~~\le \inf \{ d(a,s_1)  + d(b,s_2)\} + k~~~;s_1,s_2 \in S$

> $~~~~~~~~\le  \inf \{ d(a,s)~|~s \in S \}  + \inf \{d(b, s)~|~s \in S\} + k$
>
> I think there is an error in the last step because $\inf$ has been distributed. In general $\inf f + \inf g \le \inf ( f + g) $ where $f,g$ are two random functions. Also, see this answer where distribution of the infimum has been cited as false: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2852545/66069

Could anyone please clarify. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Separating the $s_1$ and $s_2$ dependent terms,
\begin{align*}
\require{color}
&\inf\{d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)\mid s_1,s_2\in S\}\\
&=\inf\{\inf\{d(a,s_1){\color{red}{+d(b,s_2)}}\mid s_1\in S\}\mid s_2\in S\}\\
&=\inf\{{\color{blue}\inf\{d(a,s_1)\mid s_1\in S\}}{\color{red}{+d(b,s_2)}}\mid s_2\in S\}\\
&={\color{blue}{\inf\{d(a,s_1)\mid s_1\in S\}+}}\inf\{d(b,s_2)\mid s_2\in S\}\\
&=\inf\{d(a,s)\mid s\in S\}+\inf\{d(b,s)\mid s\in S\}.
\end{align*}
The red and blue terms are independent of the immediate variable in inf, so can be pulled outside as shown.

But there is indeed a mistake in the proof you wrote:
$$
d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)+k
$$
is not $\leq\inf\{d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)\mid s_1,s_2\in S\}+k$.  One correct way is to give yourself some room first (another way is given by DanielWainfleet in the comments).  For $\varepsilon>0$, pick $s_1,s_2\in S$ so that
$$
d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)\leq\inf\{d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)\mid s_1,s_2\in S\}+\varepsilon
$$
and hence
\begin{align*}
d(a,b)&\leq d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)+d(s_1,s_2)\\
&\leq\inf\{d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)\mid s_1,s_2\in S\}+\varepsilon+k\\
&=\inf\{d(a,s)\mid s\in S\}+\inf\{d(b,s)\mid s\in S\}+k+\varepsilon
\end{align*}
Now $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, so
$$
d(a,b)\leq\inf\{d(a,s)\mid s\in S\}+\inf\{d(b,s)\mid s\in S\}+k.
$$

Comment: Could you  clarify how did the infimum distribute? It generally cannot be distributed:   

$ \inf \{~~d(a,s)+d(b,s)~∣s∈S\} \ne \inf \{d(a,s)∣s∈S\}+\inf \{d(b,s)∣s∈S\}$

Comment: They are minimizing over *different* $s_1,s_2$, so it distributes.

Comment: aah okay. I still have a small confusion. Are $s_1,s_2$ really different variables? They are just different names for the same variables $s$ to be minimized over the same set $S$?

Comment: They are different variables.  We need a point $s_1\in S$ that is close to $a$ and (possibly different) $s_2\in S$ that is close to $b$.  For example, let $X=\mathbb{R}$, $S=(-1,1)$, $a=-1$ and $b=1$.  Then you want $s_1$ to be close to $-1$ and $s_2$ to be close to $+1$.

Comment: More directly, let $A=\inf \{d(a,s_1): S_1\in S\}$ and $B=\inf \{d(b,s_2):s_2\in S\}. $ For any   $s_1,s_2\in S$ we  have $d(a,b)\le d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)+k.$ So for any $s_2\in S$ we have $d(a,b)\le$ $ \inf \{d(a,s_1)+d(b,s_2)+k: s_1\in S\}=$ $=\inf \{d(a,s_1):s_1\in S\}+d(b,s_2)+k=$ $A+d(b,s_2)+k$... et cetera..... To the proposer:  It is true that if $f,g$ are functions on a common domain $S$ then $\inf f+  \inf g \le \inf \{f(s)+g(s):s\in S\}. $  But here, with $f(s)=d(a,s)$ and $g(s) =d(b,s), $ we are looking at $\inf \{f(s_1)+g(s_2): (s_1,s_2)\in S^2\}.$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet you mean, infimum distributed because $s_1,s_2$ are different variables. correct?

Comment: @MathMan. Yes. But I would say that it might only seem  like a distributive law was applied.

Comment: @user10354138 thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, that is an error, for the reasons you cited.

I think the first error has happened one step before, when they say

$$d(a,s_1)  + d(b,s_2) \le \inf \{ d(a,s_1)  + d(b,s_2)\}$$

which is of course wrong generally. It would work with supremum, but not infimum.

If you are interested in the proof, it could go like this, using your $k$, we start with the last correct line:

$$d(a,b) \le d(a,s_1)  + d(b,s_2) + k, \quad\forall s_1,s_2\in S.$$

Now choose a sequence $s_{1n}\in S, n\ge 1$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(a,s_{1n})=\inf\{d(a,s_1),s_1\in S\}$. That's more or less the definition of the infimum. That means we have

$$d(a,b) \le d(a,s_{1n})  + d(b,s_2) + k, \quad\forall s_2\in S, s_{1n} \text { as defined above},$$

which we can rewrite as

$$d(a,b) - d(b,s_2) -k \le d(a,s_{1n}), \quad\forall s_2\in S, s_{1n} \text { as defined above}.$$

Now if we fix $s_2$ the above inequality has a constant on the left side. If we take the limit $n\to \infty$ on both sides, we get

$$d(a,b) - d(b,s_2) - k \le \inf\{d(a,s_1),s_1\in S\}, \quad\forall s_2\in S,$$

which we rewrite again as

$$d(a,b) \le \inf\{d(a,s_1),s_1\in S\} + d(b,s_2) + k, \quad\forall s_2\in S.$$

If we do the same procedure with a sequences $s_{2n}\in S, n\ge 1$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty} d(b,s_{2n})=\inf\{d(b,s_2),s_2\in S\}$, we finally get the desired outcome:

$$d(a,b) \le \inf\{d(a,s_1),s_1\in S\} + \inf\{d(b,s_2),s_2\in S\} + k.$$

Because we had the freedom to choose our $s_1$ and $s_2$ as we wanted, we could bring in the infimum in 2 cases.

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let $ A=\inf \{d(a,s):s\in S\} $ and $ B=\inf \{d(b,s):s\in S\} $ and $ k=\sup \{d(s,s'):s,s'\in S\}.$

By contradiction, suppose $ d(a,b)=A+k+B+r  \;$ with $r>0.$

Take $s_1\in S$ with $d(a,s_1)<A+r/2.$ Take $s_2\in S$ with $d(b,s_2)<B+r/2 .$ Then $$A+k+B+r=d(a,b)\le $$ $$\le d(a,s_1)+d(s_1,s_2)+d(s_2,b)\le$$ $$\le d(a,s_1)+k+d(s_2,b)<$$  $$<(A+r/2)+k+(B+r/2)=A+k+B+r$$ implying $A+k+B+r<A+k+B+r.$

Comment: Thank you  for the answer!